# What are the best practices to manage UPS in windows 2008 R2?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, monitoring, scripting, ups

with win2k3 i used the ups service to monitor usb connected UPS and launch scripts when ups meets critical battery condition.

The ups service is no more available in win2k8 and power management seems to be minimalist : in fact i can only choose to shutdown server in the critical battery action. I dont have the option to send a mail nor run a script in that case.
I dont want to install specific software like powerchute to handle battery's alerts.

How do you monitor your ups, and run specific actions when AC is down ?
Is it good to use a wmi request each X seconds to get the win32_battery counters ?

Comment: What brand UPS most manufacturers provide an application that is better than the Windows one anyway, but I see your preference to the simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing built in to take more specific action in battery status (other than notify and shutdown) for more granular action you would have to write a powershell script and monitor the win32_battery class

Comment: ok i think this is what i'll do.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice is to use the manufacturers app because windows support for them was only ever half arsed.

I don't know what answer you expect, when you acknowledge that windows doesn't do it but you don't want to install the 3rd party app that has the functionality?  Option 3: Magic unicorn.

Comment: well i don't want to be linked to a specific manufacturer, i would like something working with different models/brands of ups...

Comment: Don't want to be tied to a specific vendor? How often do you change UPS units, let alone vendors?

Comment: we have an heterogeneous parc of UPS (different manufacturers and models) and i'd like to have a working solution for all of them

Comment: you need to consider when purchasing UPSs that there isn't a standard. So your choice is reduced functionality, buy UPSs all from the same manufacturer or live with multiple proprietary software